# Plotly with ipywidgets creates multiple plots in VS Code instead of updating the already existing plot

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, plotly-python, ipywidgets

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np

# Create some data for the plots
x = np.random.rand(50)
y = np.random.rand(50)

# Create a function that will be called when the dropdown value changes
def update_plot(plot_type):
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    if plot_type == 'Scatter Plot':
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers'))
    elif plot_type == 'Box Plot':
        fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=y))
    
    fig.show()

# Create a dropdown menu
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['Scatter Plot', 'Box Plot'],
    value='Scatter Plot',
    description='Plot Type:',
)

# Display the dropdown menu
display(dropdown)

# Call the function to update the plot whenever the dropdown value changes
widgets.interactive(update_plot, plot_type=dropdown)
```

This code should generate either a scatter or a box plot with plotly depending on the selection of the dropdown menu.

When the code is run inside a cell of a .ipynb file in VS Code there is a bug: every time I change the status of the dropdown, instead of updating the already existing plot, a new plot is created below the one already existing.

I tried to run the same code in Jupyter Lab, and there, the code works flawlessly.
I tried a similar code inside VS Code using matplotlib, and with that I don't have issues in VS Code.

How can I fix the issue with plotly in VS Code?

---

VS Code version: 1.84.2
plotly: 5.18.0
ipywidgets: 8.1.1

Comment: `ipywidgets`, also known as `jupyter-widgets` or simply `widgets`, are interactive HTML widgets for `Jupyter notebooks` and the IPython kernel. So it won't work in the *.py code base...

Comment: I installed the jupyter notebook plugin in VS Code and I am running the code from a *.ipynb file, not a *.py

Comment: `display` is not defined...

Comment: The display() function should be part of the IPython.core.display module, which is automatically imported in Jupyter notebooks. `display` is not the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to clear the axes, not the figure. you are generating a new figure each time the update happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried fig.layout = {} and  fig.data = [ ] but it didn't work. Was this what you had in mind?